# Pegar uma classe que tem um determinada interface implementada nos generics

Tags: java, classes, interface, genéricos, classes-abstratas

Olá.

Eu quero fazer algo parecido com `metodo(Class<? extends ClasseAbstrata> classe)`, só que do que uma classe abstrata, quero usar uma `interface`, mas se mudo de `extends` para `implements` o eclipse começa a apontar um erro.

O que faço?

Outra dúvida é que se troco a classe abstrata por uma `interface`, e deixo `extends` (`Class<? extends Interface>`), o eclipse não aponta erro, mas não da para fazer: `public class Classe extends Interface { ...`.

Isso é erro do eclipse? Ou há algum tipo de classe que pode ser feita assim?

---

Eu tenho três classes que implementam a `interface` (`Acao`), E criei outra `interface` (`AcaoController`), e essa `interface` tem o método `public void inicializaEdicao(Class<?> classe);` e quero que ele receba todos os métodos que implementam `Acao`.

Interface:

```
public interface Acao {

    public String dadosParaGravacao();

    public Person criaPerson();

}
```

Classe `Compromisso`:

```
public class Compromisso implements Acao { 

    ...

    @Override
    public String dadosParaGravacao() {

        return new StringBuilder().append(descricao)
                .append("|").append(titulo)
                .append("|").append(importancia)
                .append("|").append(feito)
                .append("|").append(atrazado)
                .append("|").append(horario.toString())
                .append("|").append(dataDeCriacao.toString())
                .append("|").append(dataDoFinal.toString())
                .append("|").toString();

    }

    @Override
    public Person criaPerson() {

        return new CompromissoPerson(titulo, importancia, feito);

    }
}
```

Classe `Projeto`:

```
public class Projeto implements Acao { 

    ...

    @Override
    public String dadosParaGravacao() {

        return new StringBuilder().append(descricao)
            .append("|").append(titulo)
            .append("|").append(importancia)
            .append("|").append(feito)
            .append("|").append(atrazado)
            .append("|").append(dataDeCriacao.toString())
            .append("|").append(dataDoFinal.toString())
            .append("|").toString();

    }

    @Override
    public Person criaPerson() {

        return new ProjetoPerson(titulo, importancia, feito);

    }
}
```

Classe `Favorito`:

```
public class Favorito implements Acao { 

    ...

    @Override
    public String dadosParaGravacao() {

        return new StringBuilder().append(descricao)
            .append("|").append(titulo)
            .append("|").append(importancia)
            .append("|").append(link)
            .append("|").append(dataDeCriacao.toString())
            .append("|").toString();

    }

    @Override
    public Person criaPerson() {

        return new FavoritoPerson(titulo, importancia, dataDeCriacao.toString());

    }
}
```

Interface `AcaoController`:

```
public interface AcaoController {

    public List<Person> novo();

    public void inicializaEdicao(Class<?> classe);

}
```

---

O erro continua:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque não apenas `public void inicializaEdicao(Acao a);`? O que o seu controller faz que ele precisa da classe e não da instância?

Comment: Não tinha percebido isso. obrigado.

Comment: Então trocar o parâmetro para o tipo `Acao` resolveu?

Comment: Não apareceu nenhum problema. Então sim.

Answer (score 3):

Nos generics, você sempre usa as palavras-chave `extends` ou `super`. Não importa se é uma classe que `implements` uma interface ou que `extends` uma outra classe. São conceitos totalmente diferentes, eles apenas reutilizaram palavras-chave já existentes na linguagem para que novas palavras-chave não tivessem que ser introduzidas.

Assim sendo, se você tem:

```
public interface Y {}
public class X implements Y {}
```

Você declara:

```
// Aceita qualquer classe que implemente (com implements) a interface X;
// Qualquer subinterface que herde (com extends) a interface X;
// Ou aceita a própria interface Y (Y.class).
void metodo(Class<? extends Y> classe);
```

Da mesma forma que se você tem:

```
public abstract class B {}
public class A extends B {}
```

Você declara:

```
// Aceita qualquer subclasse (com extends) da classe B;
// Ou aceita a própria classe B (B.class).
void metodo(Class<? extends B> classe);
```

Nos genéricos, não importa se era `extends` ou `implements`, a palavra-chave a ser usada será sempre `extends`.

Há o caso do `super` também. Se você tem:

```
public interface K {}
public interface L {}
public interface H extends S {}
public interface S {}
public class G extends J implements K, L {}
public class F extends G implements H {}
public class M extends F {}
public class R {}
public interface Q extends H {}
```

Então com isso:

```
// Aceita qualquer superclasse ou superinterface de F, além da própria classe F (F.class).
// Aceita F.class, G.class, H.class, J.class, K.class, L.class, S.class ou Object.class.
// Não aceita M.class, R.class ou Q.class.
void metodo(Class<? super F> classe);
```

Porque enquanto o `extends` "olha para baixo" (ou seja, para tipos mais específicos), o `super` "olha para cima" (ou seja, para tipos mais generalizados).

---

Assim sendo este seu método:

```
public void inicializaEdicao(Class<?> classe);
```

Ficará assim:

```
public void inicializaEdicao(Class<? extends Acao> classe);
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @Vitor Stafusa ótima resposta!